# Prevent words from being split in Android TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `TextView` shown below

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:id="@+id/statement"
 />
```

It is getting its content from my `strings.xml` file using the following code.

```
Statement = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.statement);
Statement.setText(R.string.TransferorStatement);
```

The text in the `strings.xml` file is

```
 <string name="TransferorStatement">I a resident of the State of having “Transferred” the firearm described below swear or affirm that the information below is true and correct to the best of my knowledge and belief and that the Transferee has presented identification from the State of that matches the Transferee’s statement below.</string>
```

The Problem I am running into is that words are getting split at line endings.
From my research the

```
android:ellipsize=""
```

argument should prevent that from happening.

However I have tried every option for ellipsize and it makes no difference in the text wrapping.

[image: Image of the Problem]

Comment: It appears to be an encoding issue with the string.

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Comment: I can not remember